# Looking for the presence of composite key in three DataFrames, and concatenating DataFrames accordingly

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, join, merge

This question was very hard to word..

Here is some sample code for a reproducible example:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd    

df1 = pd.DataFrame([['a', 1, 10, 1], ['a', 2, 20, 1], ['b', 1, 4, 1], ['c', 1, 2, 1], ['e', 2, 10, 1]])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([['a', 1, 15, 2], ['a', 2, 20, 2], ['c', 1, 2, 2]])
df3 = pd.DataFrame([['d', 1, 10, 3], ['e', 2, 20, 3], ['f', 1, 15, 3]])    

df1.columns = ['name', 'id', 'price', 'part']
df2.columns = ['name', 'id', 'price', 'part']
df3.columns = ['name', 'id', 'price', 'part']    



result = pd.DataFrame([['a', 1, 10, 15, 'missing'],
['a', 2, 20, 20, 'missing'],
['b', 1, 4, 'missing', 'missing'],
['c', 1, 2, 2, 'missing'],
['e', 2, 10, 'missing', 20],
['d', 1, 'missing', 'missing', 10],
['f', 1, 'missing', 'missing', 15]])    

result.columns = ['name', 'id', 'pricepart1', 'pricepart2', 'pricepart3']
```

So there are three DataFrames:

`df1`

```
  name  id  price  part
0    a   1     10     1
1    a   2     20     1
2    b   1      4     1
3    c   1      2     1
4    e   2     10     1
```

---

`df2`

```
  name  id  price  part
0    a   1     15     2
1    a   2     20     2
2    c   1      2     2
```

---

`df3`

```
    name  id  price  part
0    d   1     10     3
1    e   2     20     3
2    f   1     15     3
```

---

The `name` and `id` is like a composite key. It may be present in all three DataFrames, just two of the three DataFrames, in just 1 of the DataFrames. To represent which DataFrame the `name, id` came from, a `part` column exists in `df1`, `df2` and `df3`.

The result I'm looking for is given by the `result` DataFrame.

```
  name  id pricepart1 pricepart2 pricepart3
0    a   1         10         15    missing
1    a   2         20         20    missing
2    b   1          4    missing    missing
3    c   1          2          2    missing
4    e   2         10    missing         20
5    d   1    missing    missing         10
6    f   1    missing    missing         15
```

Basically, I want EVERY `name`, `id` pair to be accounted for. Even if the SAME `name`, `id` comes in both `df1` and `df2`, I want separate columns for `price` from each of the `part` even if the prices in both the parts/DataFrames are the same.

In the `results` DataFrame, take row1, `a   1   10    15   missing`

What this represents is, the `name, id` pair `a  1` had a price of `10` in `df1`, `15` in `df2`, and `missing` in `df3`.

If the row value is `missing` for a specific `pricepart` that means, the `name, id` pair did not appear in that particular DataFrame!

I've used the `part` to represent the DataFrame! so, you can asusme that `part` is ALWAYS `1` in `df1`, ALWAYS `2` in `df2` and ALWAYS `3` in `df3`.

So far.. I literally just did, `pd.concat([df1, df2, df3])`

Not sure if this approach is going to lead to a dead end..

Keep in mind that the original three DataFrames are `62245 rows × 4 columns` EACH. And each DataFrame may or may not contain the `name`, `id` pair. If the `name`, `id` pair is present in EVEN 1 of the DataFrames, and not the others, I wanted that to be accounted for with a `missing` for the other DataFrames.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `pd.merge` whilst using `how='outer'`

```
# Change column names and remove 'part' column
df1 = df1.rename(columns={'price':'pricepart1'}).drop('part', axis=1)
df2 = df2.rename(columns={'price':'pricepart2'}).drop('part', axis=1)
df3 = df3.rename(columns={'price':'pricepart3'}).drop('part', axis=1)

# Merge dataframes
df = pd.merge(df1, df2, left_on=['name', 'id'], right_on=['name', 'id'], how='outer')
df = pd.merge(df , df3, left_on=['name', 'id'], right_on=['name', 'id'], how='outer')

# Fill na values with 'missing'
df = df.fillna('missing')

Out[]: 
  name  id pricepart1 pricepart2 pricepart3
0    a   1         10         15    missing
1    a   2         20         20    missing
2    b   1          4    missing    missing
3    c   1          2          2    missing
4    e   2         10    missing         20
5    d   1    missing    missing         10
6    f   1    missing    missing         15
```

Comment: I'm clearly NOT smart... If the problem statement is EVEN SLIGHTLY twisted.. I'm forced to come here.. Thanks mate!